# Simple button component not accepting variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In reviewing and making my code more modular and robust, as any programmer should, I noticed I was using a similar button component multiple times. As such I decided to create a button component and just render it with the new route link and text as in the page rendered.

I'm completely new to react (~ 5 days in learning) with a fairly well versed programming background.

**Simple component button, I use react-route-dom : Link prop to route to new pages.**

```
function ActionButton () {
    return (
        <div className="Action">
            <button className="ActionButton">
                <Link to={this.props.navLink}> 
                    {this.props.text} 
                </Link> 
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**using/constructing of the button component**

```
function ActionPage () {
    return (
        <div className="ActionPage">
            <ActionButton
                navLink="/urlLink1"
                text="btn1"
            />
            <ActionButton
                navLink="/urlLink2"
                text="btn2"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

this doesn't work, I get the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: So, just try `<ActionButton
                navLink= { "/urlLink1" }
                text= { "btn1" }
            />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a stateless functional component as you are (as opposed to a `class` based one) the component is called with `ComponentName(props)` - you can access props by updating the signature of the component to:

`ActionButton (props) {`

Which will allow you to access `props.navLink` etc inside the function.

Comment: is this good programming practises doing it the way I'm trying to in terms of how react operates?

Comment: Yes using stateless components as you have is good practice - having components as simple as they need to be is a good thing in general. You will need to use `class` components in certain situations as they allow component lifecycle and state management. But if using a stateless one get's the job done that is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Your ActionButton component is a dump component, so you have to pass the props as a argument to the function. Update your ActionButton component as shown below.

```
function ActionButton (props) {
return (
    <div className="Action">
        <button className="ActionButton">
            <Link to={props.navLink}> 
                {props.text} 
            </Link> 
        </button>
    </div>
);}
```

As you are new to React, read more about dump vs smart components here: https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43